# Get the number of lines required for UILabel from NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, uilabel

How can I get the appropriate number of lines for a UILabel based off the text from an NSString?

I am needing a cell in my UITableView to have a dynamic cell height based off of the UILabel height. That means I need to figure out how tall the UILabel will be from the NSString provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a UIKit provided category method to return a `CGSize` that will fit a string, given a number of different input parameters.

The only one that is required that I'm aware of is specifying font, but you can specify other text attributes as well.

```
CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes: @{
                  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]
              }];
```

Given that, you could probably calculate how many lines of text there are.

See the docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:

**EDIT**

You probably want to look at [`boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3aattributes%3a).  You'll pass in the size of the label, [string drawing options](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringDrawingOptions) and your text attributes (like font).

Comment: By entering in specifications for the text attributes, how will the CGSize be determined? If I have a UILabel that has constraints to be X wide, how will this method allow me to figure it out? Basically how will I know how many lines to use in a UILabel that is X wide from this method?

Comment: Using the method `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:` is the correct solution for my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

What I do nowadays is use autolayout. The label is pegged by constraints on all sides to the surrounding content view of the cell. I keep an instance of the cell on hand. When it's time to calculate the height of a cell, I fill the label with the text for that row and perform autolayout. The label automatically sizes itself to contain the text; the cell is automatically sized to fit the label; and now I learn the cell size:

```
- (CGFloat) cellHeightForLabelString:(NSString*)s {
    Cell* cell = self.practiceCell;
    UILabel* lab = cell.lab;
    lab.text = s; // no need to know font, constraints, or anything else about label
    CGFloat h = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingExpandedSize].height;
    return ceil(h) + 1;
    // The "+1" is needed because the separator subtracts from the cell internal height!
}
```

Each cell's height is memoized into an array the first time it is requested, so that if it is requested again I can just look it up in the array:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger ix = indexPath.row;
    if ([NSNull null] == self.heights[ix]) {
        NSString* s = self.trivia[ix];
        CGFloat h = [self cellHeightForLabelString:s];
        self.heights[ix] = @(h);
    }
    return [self.heights[ix] floatValue];
}
```

Comment: And you can download the working project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch08p424variableHeights/ch21p722variableHeights

Answer (score 0):

Well, before I looked it up, I'd suggested using 
sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
from the UIKIt additions of NSString. 
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aforWidth%3alineBreakMode):

However, the doc says it is deprecated since iOS 7. Therefore using it may not be advisable any more. Maybe somebody else has a better idea that is not based on deprecated functions.

Answer (score -1):

Below is what I do.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// create UILabel and set text (as per font and size)
// call [myLabel sizeToFit];
// now find the height of the UILabel
// use this height as the height of the cell
// hide this UILabel, release this UILabel
// done

}
```

This way, I ensure that the height that I get is PERFECT!!!

Comment: That looks like a great option! But how do you know how many lines the UILabel should be based on the text it holds?

Comment: This solution is wasteful, considering how many times this method is called when rendering a table.  I'd also wager that UILabel is using `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:` to figure out its frame anyway.

Comment: @Jonathan : here you will not find how many lines... now your cell height is equal to UILabel.frame.size.height... now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` your cell height is nothing but the uilabel height... let me know if I am not clear...

Comment: @BenScheirman : I don't see any effect in rendering even if I have 100 records...

Comment: @Jonathan : Also why you are concerned with number of lines? In `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you set the height of the cell... now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` your UILabel frame will be same as cell frame... I hope this what you need...